# Building a 1 layer thick brick wall over drywall

Tags: drywall, walls, masonry

Looking to lay a brick wall over drywall in my basement.  The floor is a concrete slab which covers my entire basement.  I am looking to see what issues or concerns I should have laying a 1 layer brick wall from floor to ceiling. I am concerned the wall would topple over.  How can I lag this in?

Comment: I'd be very concerned about such a thin masonry layer over such a flexible substrate. Either use full brick or use a fake brick that's not so heavy and brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the bricks would be adequately supported from below, you would use brick ties (attached to wall studs on one end, and embedded in mortar on the other) to give your brick wall vertical stability.

If you want the look of brick wall with less effort, you can just install brick-look tiles on a suitable backer board onto your existing wall.